# lost google apps script project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, incognito-mode

I have created few test projects via https://script.google.com/ using Google Chrome Incognito Window.
The problem is that I cannot find one of published projects in my Google Drive.

This is "Hello world" content service.
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyyPyHTQEiklppiU3xyJxvuCZZLLBdY-C64We4W_YlL2amWincl/exec?prefix=alert

But there was some of important code in the sources (Code.gs).
Is it possible to recover my disappeared project?

Answer (score 2):

if you truncate your app url before "exec" and replace with "edit" you get this url :
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyyPyHTQEiklppiU3xyJxvuCZZLLBdY-C64We4W_YlL2amWincl/edit

that should work ;-)

**Edit :** you could also simply use the drive's search tool since it searches for any string inside your documents : search for 'Hello world' and it will find all occurrences of this string, including your script...

Comment: Serge, thank you very much. 
It helped. I mean substitution "exec" with "edit".
But drive's search didn't find anything.

Comment: Hi Mogsdad, I should have mentioned that *you* taught me that some time ago ;-) Now it's done  !! thx btw, it's quite useful in a few cases ...